# Find one thing change another

Tags: jquery, css, find

I'm still feeling my way here.  I need to change the width of a column dependent on if another column is present (content in a CMS - I have no control over if it's there or not).

I figured it would be easy (and it probably is... I just can't see it) to do this with JQuery.

My code is:

```
$("div").find(".leftouter").(function() {
    $(".mainouter-two").css('width', '35%');
});
```

I know it finds the div with the class of leftouter but after that and I know the change of the width of the mainouter-two works by itself but all together... no joy.  Any assistance would be wonderful!

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

this does nothing. You need to do if with an if(something){do this}.

What do you want to detect? if it exists?

```
if($("div").find(".leftouter").length > 0 ){
$(".mainouter-two").css('width', '35%');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   if($("div").find(".leftouter").length >= 1)
          $(".mainouter-two").css('width', '35%');
```

Comment: Thanks!  Sorry it took me time to get back.  Was out of town.